# Next js Images work on local but not work on prod

Tags: javascript, image, text

Next js images work on local but when i try to push prod it crashing.Here is my code

[my image component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQxVJ.png)

[This is the place where i map images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diKjT.png)

[This is my part of .json file where i fetch data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4ea3.png)

[In local works properly on this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjIIR.png)

[On prod it crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfAIL.png)

Comment: You should have attached all the sources to the questions instead of posting it in the answer section

Answer (score 0):

can you print production path , image name showing space an you cross-check oncd

Comment: this is link on local: 
 http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fboats%2FALFA%27S%2F1.jpg&w=384&q=75

this in on prod :
https://sealife-dev.muratcansahin.com/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fboats%2FALFA%27S%2F1.jpg&w=384&q=75